# How can I carve out one binary file from a concatenated binary

Tags: c, binary, concatenation, fopen, fseek

Basically I'm combining two binaries using the "cat" command on Linux. 
And I want to be able to separate them again using C
this is the code I got so far

```c
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    // Getting this file 
    FILE *localFile = fopen(argv[0], "rb");

    // Naming a new file to save our carved binary
    FILE *newFile = fopen(argv[1], "wb+");

    // Moving the cursor to the offset: 19672 which is the size of this file
    fseek(localFile, 19672, SEEK_SET);

    // Copying to the new file
    char ch;
    while ( ( ch = fgetc(localFile) ) != EOF ) {
        fputc(ch, newFile);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: `fgetc` returns a `int`, not a `char`.

Comment: You wanted it to work for this example or in general ? Because if you dont know sizes and with out any delimiters seperating two files is impossible.

Comment: Where is the use of the `cat` command? This appears to be C source code, and there are no system calls from it.

Comment: I do know the size of the original file, (file1) so I want to move the cursor to that offset because the other file should be located there

Comment: Does changing `char ch;` to `int ch;`, as suggested above, solve your issue, whatever it was? If not, what is the issue?

Comment: omggg thank youuuu, I've been stressing so hard... and yea I just changed it to an int and it now works !!!!!

Comment: Oh, wait. Are you trying to modify the executable itself? I'm talking about `FILE *localFile = fopen(argv[0], "rb");`.

Comment: no, I'm just opening it because it's going to be two binaries combined, so I opened it to copy the content of the second binary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you already know where the second file starts. You can proceed as follows. (This is bare minimal)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    FILE* f1 = fopen("f1.bin", "r");
    FILE* f2 = fopen("f2.bin", "w");

    long file1_size = 1;

    lseek(fileno(f1), file1_size, SEEK_SET);

    char fbuf[100];
    int rd_status;

    for( ; ; ) {
        rd_status = read(fileno(f1), fbuf, sizeof(fbuf));

        if (rd_status <= 0)
            break;
        write(fileno(f2), fbuf, rd_status);
    }

    fclose(f1);
    fclose(f2);
    return 0;
}
```

Input File -- f1.bin

```
1F 2A
```

Output File -- f2.bin

```
2A
```

Please, modify the file names and file sizes according to your example.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. Turns out I was doing ```char ch``` where I should've done ```int ch```
How can I mark a question as solved?? :D

Comment: Yes, according to ``fgetc()`` man page, it returns the ``unsigned char`` which is typecasted to ``int``. But in less severe cases, you need to avoid reading byte by byte. Because you are performing the disc IO a greater number of times. You should consider using the variants of ``read`` for efficient codes. Pls visit this link, [accepting-answeres](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)